# Python how many points are inside a municipality

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I have two spatial datasets:
municipality

```
municipality geometry
1000         POLYGON ((4.04305 47.56271, 4.04345 47.56303, ...
1001         POLYGON ((-0.24733 45.88792, -0.24715 45.88820...
1002         POLYGON ((-0.30449 45.91087, -0.30446 45.91120...
```

points

```
points geometry
200    POINT (3617775.075 3205012.273)
201    POINT (3617529.179 3205007.754)
202    POINT (4375420.232 4093242.822)
```

I want to estimate how many points are inside each municipality. Some of these points will not be inside any municipality, some municipalities will have several points.
Here is my code:

```
import geopandas as gdp
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
import pandas as pd

points= gdp.read_file("points.shp").to_crs("epsg:4326")
municipality= gdp.read_file("municipality.shp")

df= gdp.tools.sjoin(municipality, points, predicate="within", how='left')
df.index_right.unique()
array([nan])
```

I find it very weird that none of the points are inserted in a municipality. What I am doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can provide 2 files for the code replication?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the number of points inside each municipality you can do:

```
municipality['num_points'] = municipality.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.contains(points.geometry).sum())
```

If you want to see each point to what municipality it belongs to you can execute:

```
points_by_municipality = gpd.sjoin(municipality, points).groupby('municipality', group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x)
```

Hope it works for you.